# Why this xamarin Binding Converter crashs the application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, converters

I have a boolean property that I want bind its negated value(!value)  to a button but every time I configure the converter in xaml tag, it terminates the application without exceptions, I haven't found any errors on app center. If I remove this part `, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}` everything works again but no conversion.

My xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:BooleanConverter x:Key="inverter" />
...

<ContentPage.Resources>

...

<controls:FrameButton IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}" Margin="5" CornerRadius="5">
```

And my BooleanConverter.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

public class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

FrameButton code:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CustomControls.Controls
{
    public class FrameButton : Frame
    {
        public FrameButton()
        {
            var MyTapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            MyTapGesture.Tapped += (sender, e) => { Clicked(); };
            GestureRecognizers.Add(MyTapGesture);
        }

        public async void Clicked()
        {
            await this.ScaleTo(1.1, 100);
            await this.ScaleTo(1, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding a try/catch, and/or use the debugger to step into the code and trace the error

Comment: I test with code you provided to set the bool for a button. It works well. We need more information for reproduce. Could you provide `FrameButton` for that? Did you try to uninstall and reinstall the app or test on other device?  Does the application crash again?

Comment: @Jason have tried Convert(..){ try{} catch{} } but nothing is outputted

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT yes, I tried to clean solution, rebuild and tested in two different devices. I will update my question with FrameButton right now

Comment: @Jason something new has appeared on output screen but doesn't seems be related with the try/catch:  ```[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x794bb2bce8 in tid 26734 (com.MyApp.Beta)```

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra I make the code sample to test with FrameButton. It works well. You could download from GitHub to check.  https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/Converters/inverterDemo

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I'm seeing your example right now. Thanks for that! I have a question, why did you use string IsBusy and not int?

Comment: I use string for `true` and `false`, you could use int `1` and `0`. Use the property like below: public int IsBusy { get; set; } in page4 in my code sample. And set the `IsBusy = 0;`. It works as well,

Answer (score 0):

Use a explicit cast since you always know that `value` will be a bool unless you use it wrong. Generally `ConvertBack` isn't used because it normally doesn't make sense.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

public class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !((bool)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but the issue still there... exactly same issue.

Comment: can you post a stack trace? or the output window information?

Comment: the unique information I could find is:  ```[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x794bb2bce8 in tid 26734 (com.MyApp.Beta)```

Comment: normally if you keep scrolling up in the output pane you'll be able to find the actual exception or at least a mention of your code location.

Comment: I'm cleaning everything before starting this problematic page and reading with attention but there is nothing else.

Comment: do you have an `app.xaml` where you also declare resources? if so, move your inverter declaration there. if not create a resource dictionary at that level and then move it there. get away from having a resource dictionary on each page. is it possible you have this declared in two places with the same key? that would cause a crash i think.

Comment: there isn't app.xaml. No... it's declared only at this file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because its trying to convert the IsEnabled value back.
Have you tried making it `OneWay` e.g.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay, Converter={x:StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"
```

**edit** taking into account your comment.

I believe that a SEGSEGV error is a memory segmentation fault i.e. a memory read error. So perhaps `inverter` isn't found.

I've found that some of these esoteric error messages are usually triggered by errors in XAML code.

I see that your converter declaration for the page is:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:BooleanConverter x:Key="inverter" />
...

<ContentPage.Resources>
```

Normally the declaration would be:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:BooleanConverter x:Key="inverter" />
...
    </ResourceDictionary>
<ContentPage.Resources>
```

I suspect that the relationship with the called key "inverter" isn't declared due to it not being in the `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: I was hopeful but no... same problem =(